# Multi-Index Melt _ Pivot

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble finding a way to reshape a multi-index (columns) df two ways:
 (a) where both levels of multi-index are melted except for one column  AND

(b) where the level 1 columns are melted per each level 0 column

I may have found (a) albeit in maybe not the most programmatic way and can get close but no cigar on (b)

For example, given DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dealer': {0: 'SF', 1: 'LA'},
                   'col2': {0: 1, 1: 3},
                   'col3': {0: 2, 1: 4},
                   'col4': {0: 3, 1: 6},
                   'col5': {0: 7, 1: 2},
                  })
df.columns = [['Jan','Jan','Feb','Feb','dealer'], ['cars','trucks','cars','trucks','dealer']]

Out[209]: 
   Jan         Feb        dealer
  cars trucks cars trucks dealer
0    1      2    3      7     SF
1    3      4    6      2     LA
```

I can get to (a) by:

```
melted = df.melt(id_vars = 'dealer',col_level=0, var_name='month')
melted['product']=df.melt(id_vars = 'dealer',col_level=1)['variable']
melted.sort_values('dealer', inplace=True)

melted
Out[211]: 
  dealer month  value product
1     LA   Jan      3    cars
3     LA   Jan      4  trucks
5     LA   Feb      6    cars
7     LA   Feb      2  trucks
0     SF   Jan      1    cars
2     SF   Jan      2  trucks
4     SF   Feb      3    cars
6     SF   Feb      7  trucks
```

but can't seem to pivot right to get ['dealer','product','Jan','Feb'] as column labels with values in Jan and Feb cols

```
pivotedd =  pd.DataFrame({'dealer': {0: 'LA', 1: 'LA',2: 'SF', 3: 'SF'},
                   'product': {0: 'cars', 1: 'trucks',2: 'cars', 3: 'trucks'},
                   'Jan': {0: 3, 1: 4,2:1,3:2},
                   'Feb': {0: 6, 1: 2,2:3,3:7},
                  })

Out[215]: 
   Feb  Jan dealer product
0    6    3     LA    cars
1    2    4     LA  trucks
2    3    1     SF    cars
3    7    2     SF  trucks
```

Obviously I would want the dealer and product as first columns and dates in chronological order (haven't read up on why pd.dataframe changes the order you put in the data), but that is essentially what I am after.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
df.set_index('dealer').stack(1).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1':'product'})

  dealer  product  Feb  Jan
0  (SF,)    cars    3    1
1  (SF,)  trucks    7    2
2  (LA,)    cars    6    3
3  (LA,)  trucks    2    4
```

Comment: That did exactly as I requested.  Now if I were to convert the months to date.times would I get the functionality of a datetime.index with its resampling/sorting capabilities if the whole index wasn't datetime (i.e. I still have the dealer and product columns)?

Comment: I'm not completely sure how you mean, but you can look into `pd.to_datetime`, which can convert to datetime, so you can use datetime functions (including resampling and sorting)